# Implementing a .Net Collection like class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

So, i would like to implement something like this:

```
class Collection{
   private $array;
   public function add($object){
      array_push($this->array, $object);
   }
   public function array(){
      return $this->array;
   }
}
class JustaClass{
   public $myCollection;
   public function __construct(){
      $this->myCollection = new Collection();
   }
}

$justAnObject = new JustaClass();
$justAnObject->myCollection->add(new SomeObject());
```

this works just fine, but i would like to work with it  like i do in .Net, ie, when i want to refer to the collection Object, i would like to do it directly, like:

```
foreach($justAnObject->myCollection as $collectionItem)
```

and not like

```
foreach($justAnObject->myCollection->array() as $collectionItem)
```

Is there any way I can do this? maybe a magic method, or implementing an Iiterator-like interface?

thanks

Comment: Implement Iterator or IteratorAggregate

Comment: thanks, do u want to put it as an answer, so i can accept it?

Comment: you might want to point out which .NET collection you are refering to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your `Collection` class implement the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/Iterator) or `IteratorAggregate` interfaces. There's also an [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/ArrayIterator) class, so it's really as easy as just returning an instance of that class:

```
class Collection implements IteratorAggregate {
  private $array;
  public function add($object){
    array_push($this->array, $object);
  }

  /* required by IteratorAggregate */
  public function getIterator() {
    return new ArrayIterator($this->array);
  }
}
```

You can then use your class in the following way:

```
$c = new Collection();
$c->add(1);
$c->add(2);
$c->add('we can even add strings');
foreach($c as $v) {
  doSomething($v);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is what [`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/splobjectstorage) does, so no need to code anything:

> The `SplObjectStorage` class provides a map from objects to data or, by ignoring data, an object Set. This dual purpose can be useful in many cases involving the need to uniquely identify objects.

It implements `Countable`, `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess`, so you can `foreach` it, access it with `[]` and use `count` on it. Like the description says it's a Set, so it contains no duplicate elements.

If you want to allow for duplicate elements, you can simply use `ArrayIterator` or `ArrayObject`. You can find additional Data Structures similar to the various .NET collections in

- http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

IMO, there is no point in writing a custom class unless you also need to customize behavior of any of the options mentioned above.